# SQL Select первая буква второго слова

Tags: php, sql

Прошу помощи , есть выборка результатирующая которая выводит поле fio

в FIO выводит Иванов Олег Ярославович
из этого ФИО мне нужно выводить ":Иванов О"

нагуглил решение

```
SELECT  CONCAT(':', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fio`, ' ', 1), ' ', LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fio`, ' ', -2), 1)) AS `author` 
FROM user
```

и оно вроде рабочее но если фио не полное к примеру Иванов Олег 
то моя конструкция уже работает не корректно и выводит "Иванов И"

Comment: а СУБД у вас какая? добавьте тегом пож

Comment: `LEFT(fio, 1+LOCATE(' ', fio))`. Если возможно одно слово (только фамилия) - то `LEFT(fio, 1+LOCATE(' ', CONCAT(fio, ' ')))`. Если возможен ещё и пробел в начале - то `LEFT(fio, 1+LOCATE(' ', CONCAT(TRIM(fio), ' ')))`.

Comment: у меня это решение работае корректно LEFT(fio, 1+LOCATE(' ', fio)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать что-то вроде:

```
select left(fio,charindex(' ',fio) + 1) from user
```

Или еще можно так)

```
select  string_agg(case when x.row = 2 then left(x.val,1) else x.val end,' ') 
from user 
cross apply (select row_number() over(order by fio) row, 
val = value from string_split(fio,' ')) as x 
where x.row in(1,2) 
group by fio
```